# Can I add HTML button triggers to update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview, webforms, updatepanel

Is it possible to add HTML input buttons to asp.net triggers, as I have a message box it works perfectly for a gridview which is in update panel,

but when I go to a different page of gridview, message box displays but buttons stops working, I don't know how to debug it, please help.

this is the button,

```
<input type="button" id="Button2" value="Cancel" cssclass="rightButton" />
```

and can I add it to,

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
```

OR should I not ?

Comment: I think you can debug your code in same way of debug other elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with runat server tag you use html controls in c# script.

i.e

```
<input type="button" id="Button2" value="Cancel" cssclass="rightButton" />
```

should be

```
<input type="button" id="Button2" value="Cancel" cssclass="rightButton" runat="server" />
```

and the when you double click on it(assuming VS as IDE), it will make a new click event in c# snippet. Besides its good practice to use direct html tags when complex functions are not needed, it saves time to display the page, as an asp component first translates itself in the html and then goes to browser; while this approach saves time of translation.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! to see errors ,first remove `UpdatePanel` from your code and then test elements without it,in this status if any error occurs will be shown, after test you can add it again.